# Kotlin multiplatform cannot resolved references while gradle sync succeeds

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

When I compile my kotlin multiplatform project I get `Unresolved reference` on stuffs that I use in the common module. But the gradle synchronisation works fine. You can found my project [here](https://github.com/Aklal/KotlinMppTest)

In details:

1. I followed the tutorial from [Jetbrain to build a mobile multiplatform project](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/01_Introduction?_ga=2.108616960.341572728.1590482075-523731901.1584550432). Everything works fine.
2. Then I implemented inside the common module a ktor client to request an api (jsonplaceholder). I added all the required dependencies and everything seems good. All references are resolved, I have no errors.
3. But when I compile my project with `make Project` then all the dependencies added to get ktor and so on cannot be resolved.

I guess I have a problem with the configuration of my project, when I run `./gradlew androidDependencies` it seems that there is a problem with `SharedCode` since it is sometimes marked in the command´s output as `\--- :SharedCode`.

The `build.gradle` for the project is:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-rc01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The `build.gradle.kts` for the common `SharedCode` module is:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}

kotlin {
    //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
    if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
    ::iosArm64
    else
    ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "SharedCode"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("android")

    val serializationVersion = "0.20.0"
    val ktorVersion = "1.3.2"

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serializationVersion")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktorVersion")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")//Kotlinxserializer
    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    /// selecting the right configuration for the iOS
    /// framework depending on the environment
    /// variables set by Xcode build
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val framework = kotlin.targets
            .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios")
            .binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)

    /// generate a helpful ./gradlew wrapper with embedded Java path
    doLast {
        val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.writeText("#!/bin/bash\n"
                + "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n"
                + "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n"
                + "./gradlew \$@\n")
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

And the `build.gradle` for the android app is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mpp.mpptest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation project(':SharedCode')
}
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

I read [Building Multiplatform Projects with Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html) but it did not help.

The only working project that I found is from [KaMPKit](https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit). I have set my `build.gradle(.kts)` files as they are in KaMPKit (see the branch `Set_build_gradle_as_KaMPKit`) but the `unresolved references´ problem remains.

Comment: You project link gives 404

Comment: @vizsatiz, I have fixed the link, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem. The error came because I did not declare the plugin `android.lybrary`.

Even if it is not necessary to fix the problem, I have decided to switch my `build.gradle` files to kotlin DLS, I rewrote all the `build.gradle` and I made the following changes for the shared module:

- I created a `AndroidManifest.xml`
- I added the `com.android.library` plugins
- I added a block `android`

At the end the `build.gradle.kts` for the shared module looks like this:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(Versions.min_sdk)
        targetSdkVersion(Versions.target_sdk)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

kotlin {
    //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
    if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
    ::iosArm64
    else
    ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "SharedCode"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("android")

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common", Versions.kotlin))
        implementation(Deps.Ktor.commonCore)
        implementation(Deps.Ktor.commonJson)
        implementation(Deps.Coroutines.common)
        implementation(Deps.Ktor.commonSerialization)
    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib", Versions.kotlin))
        implementation(Deps.Coroutines.jdk)
        implementation(Deps.Ktor.androidSerialization)
    }

    sourceSets["iosMain"].dependencies {
        implementation(Deps.Ktor.iosSerialization)
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    /// selecting the right configuration for the iOS
    /// framework depending on the environment
    /// variables set by Xcode build
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val framework = kotlin.targets
            .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios")
            .binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)

    /// generate a helpful ./gradlew wrapper with embedded Java path
    doLast {
        val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
        gradlew.writeText("#!/bin/bash\n"
                + "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n"
                + "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n"
                + "./gradlew \$@\n")
        gradlew.setExecutable(true)
    }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

All dependency version numbers come from a `Dependencies.kt` files (see [KaMPKit](https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit))

All dependencies are now resolved.